# Terraform JSON Error when using for_each inside of resource inside of json file

Tags: json, terraform

I'm trying to use the new for_each inside of a resource within a .tf.json file

The goal is to be able to pass a map of employees and generate a gsuite_user for each one programmatically, without having to redeclare each resource (also because modules can't be looped yet)

```
{
  "resource": {
    "gsuite_user": {
      "for_each": "${var.employee_map}",
      "employee": {
        "change_password_next_login": true,
        "name": {
          "family_name": "${each.value.last_name}",
          "given_name": "${each.value.first_name}"
        },
        "password": "password",
        "primary_email" :"${var.first_name}.${var.last_name}@email",
        "lifecycle": {
          "ignore_changes": ["password", "change_password_next_login"]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```sh
Error: Incorrect JSON value type

  on ../modules/employees/main.tf.json line 4, in resource.gsuite_user:
   4:       "for_each": "${var.employee_map}",


Either a JSON object or a JSON array is required, representing the contents of
one or more "resource" blocks.
```

My variable file is

```
{
  "employee_map": {
    "john.doe": {
      "first_name": "john",
      "last_name": "doe"
    },
    "jane.doey": {
      "first_name": "jane",
      "last_name": "doey"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is appearing because there is a missing nesting level in your resource declaration.

Taking the following native syntax declaration as an example:

```
resource "gsuite_user" "employee" {
  for_each = var.employee_map

  change_password_next_login = true
  # etc, etc
}
```

Notice that in the above the `for_each` argument is inside the `resource` block, along with the `change_password_next_login` argument and all of the others that would follow. To mimic that in JSON, similarly the `"for_each"` property must be inside the JSON object that represents that block:

```
{
  "resource": {
    "gsuite_user": {
      "employee": {
        "for_each": "${var.employee_map}",
        "change_password_next_login": true,
        "name": {
          "family_name": "${each.value.last_name}",
          "given_name": "${each.value.first_name}"
        },
        "password": "password",
        "primary_email" :"${var.first_name}.${var.last_name}@email",
        "lifecycle": {
          "ignore_changes": ["password", "change_password_next_login"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you place `for_each` immediately inside the `gsuite_user` object then the JSON decoder assumes you were trying to declare a `resource "gsuite_user" "for_each"` block, and thus attempts to interpret `"${var.employee_map}"` as the body of that block. That's not valid, because the body of a block must always be represented as a JSON object. (It could also be an array, in which case it would be declaring one or more blocks, but that doesn't make sense in this scenario because the resource block labels must be unique within a module.)